# How do you iterate a for loop with multiplication or division? [Kotlin]

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, while-loop, iterator, language-design

How do you write an iteration step to multiply, divide, or have some custom iteration function in Kotlin? I know I can use while loops instead, but for loops seem more restrictive in scope than in other languages. Is this by design?

**What is available in most other languages:**

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i *= 2) // [JavaScript]
for i := 1; i <= 10; i*=2 // [Golang]
```

**What I want to do in Kotlin (or something close to it):**

```
for(i in 1..10 step 2 * i) // [Kotlin]
```

It would be easy if we could reference the iterator in the for loop body itself, but the above will cause an 'Unresolved reference' error since `i` cannot be referenced in the iteration step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a pity that Kotlin designers decided not to support C-style `for` loops, but you can do some tricks with extension functions.

Declare infix function

```kotlin
// for increasing rangeTo (..)
infix fun IntRange.step(next: (Int) -> Int) =
        generateSequence(first, next).takeWhile { if (first < last) it <= last else it >= last }

// for decreasing downTo
infix fun IntProgression.step(next: (Int) -> Int) = (first..last).step(next)
```

and use it like following

```kotlin
for (i in 1..10 step { it * 2 }) {
    println(i)
}
```

Output

```
1
2
4
8
```

And

```kotlin
for (i in 16 downTo 1 step { it / 2 }) {
    println(i)
}
```

Output

```
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: This is nice, and answers my question exactly how I wrote it. I think I will go with a while loop over this for now though, as @konstantin says in his answer. Thank you!

Comment: @HarishVangavolu glad to help. I personally would also go for `while` loop as it seems to be more straightforward and non-hacky

Answer (score 3):

You may construct a `Sequence` and then iterate over it.

```kotlin
fun myProgression(from: Int, toInclusive: Int? = null, transform: (Int) -> Int = { it + 1 }) = when {
    toInclusive == null -> generateSequence(from, transform) //infinite sequence
    toInclusive < from -> emptySequence()
    else -> generateSequence(from) {
        val next = transform(it)
        if (next > toInclusive) null else next
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
//1, 2, 4, 8
for (i in myProgression(1, 10) { it * 2 }) {
    println(i)
}

//1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512
myProgression(1) { it * 2 }.take(10).forEach { println(it) }

//simple loop in 1..10 range
for (i in myProgression(1, 10)) {
    println(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

True, the `for` loop in Kotlin is restricted by design. It was decided to do so since complex conditions in the loop title were error-prone. I would suggest using the `while` loop for your particular case.

Comment: Yes, from what I've seen everywhere else, a while loop seems to be the most accepted way. I was just having a hard time coming to terms with that. :)